# Javascript Replace trick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having JavaScript string combinations like this,

```
str = "<div>xyz 123 <rd> </div>"
or
str = "sample text <abc>"
or
str = "Text <input type="text" /> new value <bla> ."
```

I have to find invalid tags(not having end tags) like `(<rd>, <abc>, <bla>)` and need to replace like `&lt;bla&gt;`

Can someone help to solve this. Fully in JavaScript.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request, which will be downvoted and closed. Also, how are you going to determine what is/is not valid? By your logic (anything which doesn't have a closing tag should be removed) the `<input />` element will be removed as it doesn't have a closing tag - yet is perfectly valid.

Comment: No <Input/> is valid

Comment: Thats exactly my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like this with help of **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```js
var str = `<div>xyz 123 <rd> </div>
sample text <abc>
Text <input type="text"/> new value <bla>`;


console.log(
  str.replace(/<([a-z]+)([^>]*[^\/])?>(?![\s\S]*<\/\1)/gi, function(m) {
    return $('<div/>').text(m).html(); // encoding matched text
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/dI2tM1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Refer the following answer for html encoding : [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Excellent:). Thank you very much

Comment: @JqueryRock : glad to help :)